# Do compilers reduce simple functions given constant arguments into unique instructions?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

This is something I've always thought to be true but have never had any validation. Consider a very simple function:

```
int subtractFive(int num) {
    return num -5;
}
```

If a call to this function uses a compile time constant such as

```
  getElement(5);
```

A compiler with optimizations turned on will very likely inline this. What is unclear to me however, is if the num - 5 will be evaluated at runtime or compile time. Will expression simplification extend recursively through inlined functions in this manner? Or does it not transcend functions?

Comment: I would hope that a decent compiler replaces the second expression to just 0, yes. But there's no way to be sure other than by looking at the assembly

Comment: If it's simple code I like using [this page](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) as it conveniently filters out most of the noise that `gcc -S` produces.

Comment: I'm no expert but I assume it might help to make the function `constexpr`.

Comment: If it's inlined, it's not a different function anymore.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: That will not work in C.

Comment: @Olaf if someone doesn't want to get C++ answers they shouldn't tag the question C++.

Comment: @ChrisDrew `constexpr` is not a good tool for optimization. Either computing the value at compile time is possible and makes sense, then the compiler will do so, or it isn't, then you should not try to force it. (As always, unless hard measurement facts proof otherwise.)

Comment: @ChrisDrew: I do not mind to see a C++ **comment**, but you should nevertheless clarify it does not work for all languages tagged. Otherwise you might provoke the next question "why does `constexpr` not work in C". As I understand this, OP is interested to see something working in both languages, not just one of them. Otherwise he should make that two questions actually.

Comment: @Olaf I disagree. C and C++ are two distinct languages, in general one cannot expect there to be a solution that can be considered good in both of them. If OP tags C and C++, either one is fine in an answer IMO.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I agree for far by the most questions. But this one is actually not even related to a specific programming language at all. The question would work the same for any language actually. If any, I would remove all tags of a specific language. Only somewhat acceptable justification for the tags is his example code. And that is valid at least in both tagged languages. Note that I did not criticize the comment per se, but that it did not make clear it only applies to one of the languages (and as you stated yourself, not even there necessarily).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can simply look at the generated assembly to find out. This code:

```
int subtractFive(int num) {
    return num -5;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return subtractFive(argc);
}
```

compiled with `g++ -O2` yields

```
leal    -5(%rdi), %eax
ret
```

So the function call was indeed reduced to a single instruction. This optimization technique is known as [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).

One can of course use the same technique to see how far a compiler will go with that, e.g. the slightly more complicated

```
int subtractFive(int num) {
    return num -5;
}

int foo(int i) {
    return subtractFive(i) * 5;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return foo(argc);
}
```

still gets compiled to

```
leal    -25(%rdi,%rdi,4), %eax
ret
```

so here both functions where just eliminated at compile time. If the input to `foo` is known at compile time, the function call will (in this case) simply be replaced by the resulting constant at compile time ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb3a9e69475320eb)).

The compiler can also combine this inlining with constant folding, to replace the function call with its fully evaluated result if all arguments are compile time constants. For example,

```
int subtractFive(int num) {
    return num -5;
}

int foo(int i) {
    return subtractFive(i) * 5;
}

int main() {
  return foo(7);
}
```

compiles to

```
mov     eax, 10
ret
```

which is equivalent to

```
int main () {
    return 10;
}
```

A compiler will always do this where it thinks it is a good idea, and it is (usually) way better in optimizing code on this low level than you are.

Comment: I'd say it will always do this if you tell it to do so (or if you don't tell it not to do so). IOW, it depends on the compiler flags.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well in this simple case, it will most certainly always inline (if it can actually see the definition, else only via LTO). But one should certainly not start to tell the compiler explicitly what to inline unless one has proven by profiling that the compiler made bad decisions.

Comment: But what about debug builds? I'd be surprised if a breakpoint in `subtractFive` was not hit because the compiler unconditionally inlines the function.

Comment: @ChristianHackl In debug builds there is no inlining of course, but the performance of debug builds does not matter anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do a little test; consider the following

```
int foo(int);
int bar(int x) { return x-5; }
int baz() { return foo(bar(5)); }
```

Compiling with `g++ -O3` the asm output for function `baz` is

```
xorl    %edi, %edi
jmp _Z3fooi
```

This code loads a 0 in the first parameter and then jumps into the code of `foo`. So the code from bar is completely disappeared and the computation of the value to pass to foo has been done at compile time.

In addition returning the value of calling the function became just a jump to the function code (this is called "tail call optimization").

Answer (score 1):

A smart compiler will evaluate this at compile time and will replace the getElement(5) because it will never have a different result. None of the variables are considered volatile.